# Detect which DragDropEffects when dragging from Desktop or Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When dragging a file from the Desktop or from Windows Explorer, the `DragDropEffects` is always `Copy | Move | Link` , whether pressing Ctrl or not.

How do I detect which one it really is?

Comment: I cant understand what your problem is. The `dragdrop` happens in your application or another?

Comment: It is up to you to decide what the proper `DragDropEffects` should be when the user is pressing the control key and handle it accordingly in the drag events.

Comment: @Anthony Perhaps you are correct. I expected this to be handled by the initiator, just as the e.AllowedEffect is set by it. (And handle the changes using GiveFeedback or QueryContinueDrag.)

Comment: The initiator has absolutely no clue what your desire with the information is and it cannot be their responsibility to respond. Perhaps dropping a file from Windows Explorer actually copies the icon representing the file into your app? That is a completely valid use-case for certain applications and those application have to determine the proper effect, Windows Explorer cannot anticipate all the ways you may use the information it is providing you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the initiator of the drag operation only uses the `DragDropEffects` as a general suggestion, and so is not responsible to update it, since the target is the one making the decision anyway. So it's all up to the target.